# Laravel / VirtualBox / Mac permissions error

Tags: linux, laravel, debian

I am running debian on my virtualbox on my Macbook Pro.

When building my Laravel application - I have set my permissions locally to be 777 on public, storage and bootstrap.

Every time I logout / in I then get another permissions error:

[image]

My mount permissions are:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o auto,exec,rw,uid=1000,gid=33 BASE ./BASE
```

Can anyone advise what I need to do to fix this? I've tried sticky bit, but no joy.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked permissions from inside debian box?

Comment: Yes, I did the same chmod there too and same problem after a login/out.

Answer (score 1):

777 on storage does not mean 777 on `storage/framework/sessions`.

CHMOD the following directories to 0777 as well: `storage/framework/sessions` and `storage/framework/cache`

Comment: Hi there - I actually did chmod -R 777 storage/ but there is still no joy as when I logout and back in, it reappears!

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
./artisan cache:clear
```

after the *recursive chmod command* was inserted

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfourtunately still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

from the cheap seats, this sequence of code works for me each time I mess up my laravel permissions. You can use the script and update the variable or just find replace with your info for each command

```
#!/bin/bash
#set local variables
fullpath=/path/to/your/laravelproject
localuser=yourlocalusername

#make sure your local user is in the apache group
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $localuser

#give ownership of directory to apache group
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $fullpath

#set all files to 644 and directorys to 755
sudo find $fullpath -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
sudo find $fullpath/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

#chown a bunch more to make sure it knows you mean business
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $fullpath
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $fullpath/
sudo chown -R $localuser:www-data $fullpath/

#move into laravel project directory
cd $fullpath/

#give apache group ownership and write to storage and cache
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

#give local user and apache group ownership and write to storage and cache
sudo setfacl -Rdm u:$localuser:rwx,u:www-data:rwx storage
sudo setfacl -Rm u:$localuser:rwx,u:www-data:rwx storage

#set artisan back to executable
sudo chmod +x artisan

#rebuild npm because it gets mad
npm rebuild
```